# Output logs to dynamically created folder structure (based on the current date), using upstart to create the service

Tags: bash, scripts, upstart, stdout

I have the following upstart configuration:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]


respawn 
respawn limit 99 5
#respawn is used to start the nodejs again, even if it fails.

env NODE_ENV=production
env PROJ=/home

script
    cd $PROJ
    cd htdocs
    exec sudo /opt/nodejs/bin/node app.js 2>&1 >> $PROJ/logs/$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M").log
end script
```

This appends (and creates if it doesn't exist), to the dynamic file that gets created every minute, any STDOUT and STDERR messages. Now I wanted to have actual folders, as in

> /logs/2018/05/29/10_05.log

but changing the code to

```
exec /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node app.js 2>&1 >> $PROJ/logs/$(date +"%Y")/$(date +"%m")/$(date +"%d")/$(date +"%I_%M").log
```

doesn't give the expected output, becase the folder does not exist. I thought about adding a control in the script, that checks if the folder does exist or not, and it creates it if not, but I'm expecting it to be run only once, the time when the script gets executed, and not on every STDOUT message.

Is there any solution to this?

Thank you

Comment: From the code provided I doubt that you get a new log file every minute, expect if your nodejs app is constantly terminating, at least every minute.  The output redirection in `exec` line is set up with the value returned by `date` at that moment when launching the application.

Comment: Yes you are right actually, now that I checked it hadn't created new files.